# Comparing elements of keys in a list of Python dictionaries and return a key based on max value of one key and prefex of another

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
data = [{'contactCount': 0,
    'creationDate': 1581004876000,
    'lastModifiedDate': 1581004876000,
    'mailingListId': 'ML1010',
    'name': 'NIP_2020-02-06',
    'ownerId': 'GR_AB'},
{'contactCount': 0,
    'creationDate': 1581004875000,
    'lastModifiedDate': 1581004875000,
    'mailingListId': 'ML1011',
    'name': 'NH_2020-02-06',
    'ownerId': 'GR_AB'},
{'contactCount': 0,
    'creationDate': 1581004874000,
    'lastModifiedDate': 1581004874000,
    'mailingListId': 'ML1012',
    'name': 'LH_2020-02-06',
    'ownerId': 'GR_AB'},
{'contactCount': 0,
    'creationDate': 1580942151000,
    'lastModifiedDate': 1580942151000,
    'mailingListId': 'ML1013',
    'name': 'NIP_2020-02-05',
    'ownerId': 'GR_AB'},
{'contactCount': 0,
    'creationDate': 1580942151000,
    'lastModifiedDate': 1580942151000,
    'mailingListId': 'ML1014',
    'name': 'NH_2020-02-05',
    'ownerId': 'GR_AB'},
{'contactCount': 0,
    'creationDate': 1580942151000,
    'lastModifiedDate': 1580942151000,
    'mailingListId': 'ML1015',
    'name': 'LH_2020-02-05',
    'ownerId': 'GR_AB'},
{'contactCount': 5,
    'creationDate': 1580496243000,
    'lastModifiedDate': 1580496295000,
    'mailingListId': 'ML1016',
    'name': 'NIP_2020-02-01',
    'ownerId': 'GR_AB'}]
```

I need mailingListId which has max(creationDate) and startswith name(NIP):
 output `ML1010`

I tried to get the max(creationDate) using the code snippet below:

```
mailingListId = max(data, key=lambda x:x['creationDate'])['mailingListId']
```

However, I need `and` condition with `name` key starting with '`NIP`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` to apply the other condition:

```
mailingListId = max(
    filter(lambda x: x['name'][:3] == 'NIP', data),
    key=lambda x:x['creationDate']
)['mailingListId']
```